# Substitute a regular expression by text in between the regular expression

Tags: regex, vim, replace, text-processing, capture-group

Suppose I want to change

```
\hl{abc}
\{}
{
}
\hl{12}
```

to

```
abc
\{}
}
{
12
```

i.e. I want to remove `\hl{` and `}` from around what's inside them. How can I do this in vim? I was considering `:s/\\hl{.*}//g` but that also takes away the text in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\(…\)` (see [`:help /\(`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28)) to capture the text in between, and use `\1` (see [`:help s/\1`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5C1)) to make use of it in the substitution: `:s/\\hl{\(.*\)}/\1/g`.